# MCAR test warning: NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Tags: r, missing-data

I keep having this warning even though I made sure all datapoints are integers. Can I just ignore the warning? My data frame is very large though(68263 rows, 85 columns), could that be the reason?

I tried as.numeric() to convert the data again to integers. But the warning still shows up. I also tried testing on smaller subsets of the data frame and the warning didn't exist for when there are only no more than 30 variables.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using the MCAR test from either the package **naniar** or **misty**.

So this would be

```
naniar::mcar_test()
misty::na.test()
```

Here is the issue (info from misty na.test help file):
Let me cite from the

This function is based on the `prelim.norm` function in the `norm` package which **can handle about 30 variables**.

Note that the `mcar_test` function in the `naniar` package is also based on the `prelim.norm` function which results are not trustworthy whenever the following warning message is pronted on the console:

> In norm::prelim.norm(data) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer
> range

With more than 30 variables specified in the argument x, the `prelim.norm` function might run into numerical problems leading to results that are not trustworthy. In this case it is recommended to reduce the number of variables specified in the argument x. If the number of variables cannot be reduced, it is recommended to use the `LittleMCAR` function in the `BaylorEdPsych` package which can deal with up to 50 variables. However, this package was removed from the CRAN repository and needs to be obtained from the archive along with the `mvnmle` which is needed for using the LittleMCAR function.

Which means, at the moment there is no suitable package on CRAN, but you can install `BaylorEdPsych` from the [CRAN Archive](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BaylorEdPsych/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But if we have 80+ variables, is there any method can we can use? Or would it make sense to test subsets of the dataset and then combine the results?